# Vue v-model binded html element fails to update Vue instance when a separate JS entity binds and then changes the data

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue.js as the main two-way data binding tool on a remote control I and building for my alarm clock: [read more here](https://github.com/gilgameshskytrooper/Prometheus).

A publicly accessible version of a running instance of the server can be found [here](http://138.197.214.136:8080/)
[image: Website]

Most of the page is using pure Vue or JavaScript to render items. But I saw that [bootstrap color picker](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-use-bootstrap-colorpicker-example-codeexample.html) was an easy choice to implement a color picker, I chose this instead. As using normal Vue along with this color picker gave me lots of weird issues with not having access to pre-rendered variables of the Vue root instance, I used `document.getElementById().style.display = "...";` to render or hide the color picker (The color picker is part of the settings tab, and hence, it should be hidden when accessing home or about, or when LED setting functionality is disabled using the toggle).

Below is the the definition of my Vue app instance: As you can see, I am defining the color picker code as the last element I define:

```
<div id="app"> <!--Vue.js-->

    <nav v-bind:class="active" v-on:click.prevent style="position: fixed !important; left: 50% !important; margin-top:140px !important; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;">
        <a href="#" class="home" id="home" v-on:click="makeActive('home')">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="settings" id="settings" v-on:click="makeActive('settings')">Settings</a>
        <a href="#" class="about" id="about" v-on:click="makeActive('about')">About</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="pagetitle">
        <p id="atomicclock">Prometheus Clock</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form id="snoozeform" action="/snooze" method="post" ><input id="snooze" type="submit" name="snooze" value="Snooze"></input></form>
        <div id="nd1" onClick="document.getElementById('snoozeform').submit();"></div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div id="homecontent" v-if="active=='home'">
    <div id="main" >

        <div id="leftside">
            <div v-for="(alarm, index) in alarmsleft" :id="alarm.name">
                <input v-model="alarmsleft[index].time" class="time" type="time"></input>
                <button @click="submittimeleft(index)">Submit Time</button>

                <br>
                <br>

                <label class="switch">
                <input :value="alarmsleft[index].sound" v-if="alarmsleft[index].sound=='on'" @click="submitsoundleft(index)" type="checkbox" /checked>
                <input :value="alarmsleft[index].sound" v-else @click="submitsoundleft(index)" type="checkbox">
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                </label>
                </form>
                <label>Sound</label>

                <br>
                <br>

                <label class="switch">
                <input :value="alarmsleft[index].vibration" v-if="alarmsleft[index].vibration=='on'" @click="submitvibrationleft(index)" type="checkbox" /checked>
                <input :value="alarmsleft[index].vibration" v-else @click="submitvibrationleft(index)" type="checkbox">
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                </label>
                </form>
                <label>Vibration</label>

                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

            </div> <!--alarm.name-->

        </div><!--leftside-->

        <div id="rightside"> 
            <div v-for="(alarm, index) in alarmsright" :id="alarm.name">
                <input v-model="alarmsright[index].time" class="time" type="time"></input>
                <button @click="submittimeright(index)">Submit Time</button>

                <br>
                <br>

                <label class="switch">
                <input :value="alarmsright[index].sound" v-if="alarmsright[index].sound=='on'" @click="submitsoundright(index)" type="checkbox" /checked>
                <input :value="alarmsright[index].sound" v-else @click="submitsoundright(index)" type="checkbox">
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                </label>
                </form>
                <label>Sound</label>

                <br>
                <br>

                <label class="switch">
                <input :value="alarmsright[index].vibration" v-if="alarmsright[index].vibration=='on'" @click="submitvibrationright(index)" type="checkbox" /checked>
                <input :value="alarmsright[index].vibration" v-else @click="submitvibrationright(index)" type="checkbox">
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                </label>
                </form>
                <label>Vibration</label>

                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

            </div><!--alarm.name-->

        </div><!--rightside-->

    </div><!--homecontent-->
    </div><!--main-->

    <div v-else-if="active=='settings'" id="settingscontent">

    <div id="afterclock">

        <div id="afterclockleft">
            <br>
            <br>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column-small-12 padd0 align-center">
                        <div id="drop-box">
                            <h3><em>Change Alarm Audio</em></h3>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div><!--drop-box-->
                    </div><!--column-small-12-->
                    <div class="column-small-12 padd0">
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                    </div><!--column-small-12...-->
                </div><!--row-->

            </form>
            <br>
            <p>Current Track: {{this.trackinfo}}</p>
            <br>



        </div><!--afterclockleft-->

        <div id="afterclockright">
            <br>
            <h3><em>Enable IP Change Email Notifications</em></h3>
            <br>
            <br>

            <label class="switch">
                <input :value="enableemail" v-if="enableemail==true" @click="submitenableemail()" type="checkbox" /checked>
                <input :value="enableemail" v-else @click="submitenableemail()" type="checkbox">
                <div class="slider round"></div>
            </label>



                <div v-if="enableemail==true" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px;">
                    <button @click="submitemail()" style="float: right;">Submit New Email</button>
                    <input v-model="email" class="text" type="text" style="float: right;"></input>
                </div><!--v-if-->

            <div v-else>
                <br>
            </div><!--v-else-->

            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3><em>Use Custom Sound Card</em></h3>
            <label class="switch">
                <input :value="customsoundcard" v-if="customsoundcard==true" @click="submitcustomsoundcard()" type="checkbox" /checked>
                <input :value="customsoundcard" v-else @click="submitcustomsoundcard()" type="checkbox">
                <div class="slider round"></div>
            </label>



        </div> <!--id="afterclockright"-->
    </div><!--afterclock-->

</div><!--settingscontent-->

<div v-else-if="active=='about'" id="aboutcontent">
    <img src="img/home.jpg" style="left: 50%; margin-right: -50%;"/>
</div><!--aboutcontent-->

<div id="colordiv" style="float: left; padding-left: 10%;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>Change the LED Settings of the Nixie Clock<h3>
    <br>
    <h4>Enable or Disable LED<h4>
    <label class="switch">
        <input :value="enableled" v-if="enableled==true" @click="submitenableled()" type="checkbox" /checked>
        <input :value="enableled" v-else @click="submitenableled()" type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
</div> <!--id="colordiv"-->

<div style="float: left; padding-left: 10%;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4 id="colorh4">Change LED Color</h4>
    <input v-model="colors" type="text" id="color" style="background: black !important;">
    <button id="colorbutton" @click="submitcolors()">Submit New Color</button>
</div><!--end float left div-->

</div><!--app-->
```

Then, Here is my script definitions:

```
    <script>
        var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                alarmsleft: [],
                alarmsright: [],
                trackinfo: [],
                email: [],
                enableemail: [],
                customsoundcard: [],
                active: 'home',
                colors: [],
                enableled: [],
            },




            methods: {



                makeActive: function(item){

                    var elem = document.getElementById(this.active);
                    elem.setAttribute("style","color: #5e5b64 !important; border-bottom: none");
                    this.active = item;
                    var elem = document.getElementById(this.active);
                    elem.setAttribute("style","color: #ffffff !important; border-bottom: 3px solid white");
                    if (this.active == 'settings') {
                        document.getElementById("colordiv").style.display = "";
                        if (this.enableled == true) {
                            document.getElementById("color").style.display = "";
                            document.getElementById("colorh4").style.display = "";
                            document.getElementById("colorbutton").style.display = "";
                            document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = "";
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("color").style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById("colorh4").style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById("colorbutton").style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = "none";
                        }
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("colordiv").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("color").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("colorh4").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("colorbutton").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = "none";
                    }

                },


                submittimeright(arg) {
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/time",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                name: this.alarmsright[arg].name,
                                value: this.alarmsright[arg].time 
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submittimeleft(arg) {
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/time",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                name: this.alarmsleft[arg].name,
                                value: this.alarmsleft[arg].time 
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submitsoundright(arg) {
                    if (this.alarmsright[arg].sound == 'on') {
                        this.alarmsright[arg].sound = 'off';
                    } else {
                        this.alarmsright[arg].sound = 'on';
                    }
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/sound",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                name: this.alarmsright[arg].name,
                                value: this.alarmsright[arg].sound 
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submitsoundleft(arg) {
                    if (this.alarmsleft[arg].sound == 'on') {
                        this.alarmsleft[arg].sound = 'off';
                    } else {
                        this.alarmsleft[arg].sound = 'on';
                    }
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/sound",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                name: this.alarmsleft[arg].name,
                                value: this.alarmsleft[arg].sound 
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submitvibrationright(arg) {
                    if (this.alarmsright[arg].vibration == 'on') {
                        this.alarmsright[arg].vibration = 'off';
                    } else {
                        this.alarmsright[arg].vibration = 'on';
                    }
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/vibration",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                name: this.alarmsright[arg].name,
                                value: this.alarmsright[arg].vibration 
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submitvibrationleft(arg) {
                    if (this.alarmsleft[arg].vibration == 'on') {
                        this.alarmsleft[arg].vibration = 'off';
                    } else {
                        this.alarmsleft[arg].vibration = 'on';
                    }
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/vibration",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                name: this.alarmsleft[arg].name,
                                value: this.alarmsleft[arg].vibration 
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submitenableemail() {
                    if (this.enableemail == true) {
                        this.enableemail = false;
                    } else {
                        this.enableemail = true;
                    }
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/enableemail",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                value: this.enableemail,
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submitcustomsoundcard() {
                    if (this.customsoundcard == true) {
                        this.customsoundcard = false;
                    } else {
                        this.customsoundcard = true;
                    }
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/customsoundcard",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                value: this.customsoundcard,
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submitemail() {
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/newemail",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                value: this.email, 
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submitenableled() {
                    if (this.enableled == true) {
                        this.enableled = false;
                        document.getElementById("color").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("colorh4").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("colorbutton").style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        this.enableled = true;
                        document.getElementById("color").style.display = "";
                        document.getElementById("colorh4").style.display = "";
                        document.getElementById("colorbutton").style.display = "";
                    }
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/submitenableled",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                value: this.enableled,
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

                submitcolors() {
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/submitcolors",
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {
                                value: this.colors, 
                            }
                        }
                    );
                },

            },


            created() {
                var elem = document.getElementById(this.active);
                elem.setAttribute("style","color: #ffffff !important; border-bottom: 3px solid white");
                document.getElementById("colordiv").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("color").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("colorh4").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("colorbutton").style.display = "none";

                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

                $.getJSON('../json/alarms.json')
                    .done(data => {
                        this.alarmsleft = data.slice(0, 2);
                        this.alarmsright = data.slice(2);
                    });

                    $.get('../json/email')
                        .done( data => {
                        this.email = String(data).replace(/\n/g, '');
                });

                $.get('../json/enableemail')
                    .done( data => {
                        if (data.replace(/\n/g, '') == "true") {
                            this.enableemail = true;
                        } else {
                            this.enableemail = false;
                        }
                });

                $.get('../json/trackinfo')
                    .done( data => {
                        this.trackinfo = String(data).replace(/\n/g, '');
                });

                $.get('../json/colors')
                    .done( data => {
                        this.colors = String(data).replace(/\n/g, '');
                });

                $.get('../json/customsoundcard')
                    .done( data => {
                        if (data.replace(/\n/g, '') == "true") {
                            this.customsoundcard = true;
                        } else {
                            this.customsoundcard = false;
                        }
                });

                $.get('../json/enableled')
                    .done( data => {
                        if (data.replace(/\n/g, '') == "true") {
                            this.enableled = true;
                        } else {
                            this.enableled = false;
                        }
                });



            },

        })


            var nd = new NixieClock();
            nd.id = 'nd1';
            nd.urlCharsetImage = 'nixie/zm1080_l2_09bdm_90x150_8b.png';
            nd.charWidth = 90;
            nd.charHeight = 150;
            nd.extraGapsWidths[1] = 12;
            nd.extraGapsWidths[3] = 12;
            nd.charGapWidth = 10;
            document.getElementById(nd.id).parentNode.style.background = "black";
            document.getElementById(nd.id).parentNode.style.border = "2px solid #AAAAAA";
            nd.init();
            nd.run();
            nd.setText('-1.234567890');


            function showColor(){
                if (this.active == "settings")  {
                    console.log("makeActive()");
                    this.makeActive();
                }
            }

            $(function(){

                $("#drop-box").click(function(){
                    $("#file").click();
                });

                $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }); 

                $('input[type=file]').on('change', fileUpload);

                function fileUpload(event){  

                    $("#drop-box").html("<p>"+event.target.value+" uploading...</p>");
                    files = event.target.files;
                    var data = new FormData();
                    var error = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        var file = files[i];
                        console.log(file.size);
                        if (!file.type.match('audio.*')) {
                            $("#drop-box").html("<p> Audio only. Select another file</p>");
                            error = 1;
                        } else {
                            data.append('audio', file, file.name);
                        }
                    }

                    if(!error){
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("POST", "/upload", true);
                        xhr.send(data);
                        xhr.onload = function () {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            $("#afterclock").html("\
                            <div id='afterclockleft'>\
                                <form enctype='multipart/form-data'>\
                                    <div class='row'>\
                                        <div class='column-small-12 padd0 align-center'>\
                                            <div id='drop-box'>\
                                                <p>Select Files</p>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                        <div class='column-small-12 padd0'>\
                                            <input type='file' name='file' id='file' />\
                                        </div>\
                                    </div>\
                                </form>\
                            </div>\
                            <br>\
                            <p>File Uploaded. Select more files</p>");
                        } else {
                            $("#afterclock").html("<p> Error in upload, try again.</p>");
                        }
                    };
                }
            }

            });

        </script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.3.3/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.3.3/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $('#color').colorpicker({});
    </script>
```

As you can see, I am not relying on the "v-if" code to render or not render the color picker code (as this gave me lots of problems). Instead, since I know going to the root of the page will automatically load home due to the default data value:

```
data: {
    ...
    active: 'home',
    ...
}
```

I use the created() functin to hide all elements of the color by using `document.getElementById("").style.display = "none";`

Then, as part of the makeActive() method which gets called when the user clicks one of the buttons in Home, Settings, or About, Home and About will hide the color picker in the same manner while Setting will show the color via: `document.getElementById("color").style.display = "";`.

Now pretty much, the functionality of the color picker is pretty much perfect concerning where it does not needs to interact with Vue. For example, Changing the values of the color by typing results in the correct behavior (changes both the location of the dot on the color map AND the Vue color data).

[image: success1]
[image: success2]

However, when using the color map to directly make changes the value of the text box, this change is not reflected on value of the Vue color data

[image: fail]

My question is how can I reflect changes made via the color map (which correctly changes the text), to also change the value of data.colors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Vue and ColorPicker are independent components. You should bind a change event handler to ColorPicker so that it links up to Vue. When it gets changed, it should tell Vue that the values are changed, and vice versa. This is the minimal solution that you should try:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        colors: ''
    },
    methods: {
        setColorToVue: function(hex) {
            Vue.set(this, 'colors', hex);
        },
        setColorToColorPicker: function(hex) {
            $("#color").colorpicker('setValue', hex);
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        var self = this;
        $('#color').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(e) {
            self.setColorToVue(e.color.toHex());
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.setColorToColorPicker('#000000');
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.3.3/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.3.3/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
  {{colors}}
  <br />
  <input id="color" type="text" />
</div>
```